# Como DateTime com null?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-core, datetime

Basicamente, eu preciso filtrar de uma tabela do banco de dados alguns itens cujo o valor do campo de deleted_at (um campo do tipo DateTime) seja igual a null, exemplo:

[Print tirada do banco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8DrJ.png)

Para isso eu usei o seguinte código:

```
var banks = await context.BanksInstaller
                .Where(x => x.InstallerId == installerId && x.DeletedAt == null)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Eu sei que isso não é o mais correto a se fazer, mas eu também já tentei de outras formas:

```
var banks = await context.BanksInstaller
                .Where(x => x.InstallerId == installerId && x.DeletedAt == DBNull.Value)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Porém nenhuma delas com sucesso

Comment: no c# o Datetime não pode ser null, então é por isso que você não encontra o resultado, talvez setando ele pra nullable (acrescentando o "?" a variavel) você consiga filtrar corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

O DateTime pode ser recebido como Nullable, nesse caso basta adicionar um ? após o tipo, possibilitando nesse caso ser feita a verificação de != null ou utilizar o atributo HasValue conforme abaixo:

Assim como o @Lucas Miranda mencionou:

```
DateTime? suaData = null;

if (!suaData.HasValue)
{
    //operação
}
```

Ou assim já em seu código (se for .net5 ou 6)

```
var banks = await context.BanksInstaller
                .Where(x => x.InstallerId == installerId && x.DeletedAt.HasValue is false)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Resposta bem cirúrgica e direto ao ponto. 